# php connect to mysql

Tags: trisquel, php5, mysql-connection

I am using [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info) 7.0 LTS and installed `php5` and `php5-mysql`. All php scripts working properly.(I used to write my-learning scripts in `/var/www/html/xyz.php` and all is working by `http://localhost/xyz.php`properly) Now I want to create database using php and hence I am visiting [w3schools' tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).

I've written following code in `data.php` under `/var/www/html/`:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

But When I open `http://localhost/data.php`, blank page appeared!

I Also tried:

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I am missing some packages which requires for installation of MySQL with PHP5. Information provided on [community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Installing_MYSQL_with_PHP_5) at Ubuntu Documentation helps me:

Required packages are :

```
mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

And I had installed only `php5-mysql` so I've installed all packages by following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

And Now php displays **"Connected successfully"**!